# C# assign a sub class object with a class object

Tags: c#, object, reference

I wamt to update one element in sub class list and it does not work. why?
code example here:

```
//it is second paymentAction in Actions.
playAction setAction = play.Actions.Find(ActionType.Set);

//pa is playAction object with values inside. 
setAction=pa;

/// in debug mode, the Actions[1] in play object didn't change. It still contain old values.
```

Comment: And why should it change?

Comment: Have you tried for example `setAction.someprop=pa.someprop` ?

Comment: What exactly does your codes do. We need some more indepth code and explanation. First of all I don't know whether playAction is a class, enum, type, struct etc. nor do I know what the Find() method does. I don't have any knowledge of pa and what it's a reference to, but I assume it's just another playAction reference? If playAction is a class ten as soon as you set setAction to pa then the returned playAction from Find() doesn't even matter as the reference is replaced.

Comment: yes, it will change if I assgin property one by one. but why can't I assign the whole object?

Comment: @AmyLynn good time to read some docs about reference types in c#

Comment: Ok. playAction is a class object. play is a class object. Actiontype is enum. Actions is IList. pa is another object of playaction contain values

Comment: Well in your code example the return value of Find() gets replaced by the reference of pa. Which means whatever values are used will always be pa's. To just modify setAction's properties to some of pa's simply set the variables manually. ex. setAction.something = pa.something;

Answer (score 1):

The variable `setAction` will contain a reference to the object found in the list, i.e. a copy of the reference stored in the list.

When you assign a new object to the variable `setAction`, that will only replace the reference in the variable. As it's a copy of the reference in the list, the list is unaffected.

You need to get the index of the item in the list, so that you can replace the reference that is stored in the list:

```
play.Actions[index] = pa;
```